# Ranges - VBA - Why does this code not work?

Tags: vba, excel

I am try to fill some gaps in my VBA knowledege and I am confused as to why this code does not work in VBA:

```
Sub RangeTest()

Dim TemplateRange As Range
Set TemplateRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A7:BO200")

For Each thing In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A7:BO200").Columns(2)
    Debug.Print thing
Next thing

End Sub
```

Is a range not a group of other objects that you can iterate through?  Thinking about it now, I guess it might not be.  I noticed that I can iterate through the .values of the range.  But I guess the range itself is simply one object?

Comment: Well you could just iterate over each cell,  `For Each thing In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A7:BO200").Columns(2).Cells`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must say which collection in the `.Columns()` object you want to use; in this case, the `.Cells` collection seems what you want:

```
Sub RangeTest()
    Dim TemplateRange As Range
    Set TemplateRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A7:BO200")
    For Each thing In TemplateRange.Columns(2).Cells
    ' This is what you want to use, I think --^^^^^^
        Debug.Print thing
    Next thing
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, yeah I like the way you explained that!  I hadn't considered that I  must specify that collection in the columns object that I want!  Oh and I just retyped the range because I was trying different things to see where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you change

```
Debug.Print thing
```

to

```
thing.Select
```

you will see that 'thing' is the entire range of column 2 in your range (So B7:B200). If you want to iterate through each of the cells in this range you can change your For... statement to

```
For Each thing In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A7:BO200").Columns(2).Cells
```

Comment: I love your approach of using `.select` to find out more information of what the object was that I was trying to iterate through!  Strangely, I hadn't thought of using this to kind of debug my issue.